# How do I convert a BigInt to a ubyte[]?

Tags: d

I have a long number I'd like to encode:

eg. 421400434911950871535

What I'd like to do is represent it in a variety of encodings, eg. Base64, ASCII85 or Base32.

In order to do this I think I probably need to get it into a `ubyte[]`, based on the API of std.base64. I'm having trouble working out how to do it. I can get it to a hex string as follows:

```
import std.stdio;
import std.bigint;
import std.conv;

void main() {
    BigInt bignumber = ("421400434911950871535");

    string hexstr;

    bignumber.toString(delegate (foo){hexstr = to!string(foo); }, "%X");

    writeln(hexstr);

;}
```

Which gives me

```
"16_D81B16E0_91F31BEF".
```

What I'd like to do is get it into a `ubyte[]` that looks like this:

```
[16, D8, 1B, 16, E0, 91, F3, 1B, EF]
```

Is there simple way to do this?

Comment: Aargh, it would be easy if the internal data wasn't private! edit: but it is... and aside from modifying the source, i don't see any way to get at it :(

Comment: What I really want is what node.js does: new Buffer("250001000192CD0000002F6D6E742F72", "hex") :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Best answer so far, [thanks to 'Anonymous' on the D forums](http://forum.dlang.org/post/welnhsfiqyhchagxilet@forum.dlang.org):

```
import std.conv: parse;
import std.array: array;
import std.range: chunks;
import std.algorithm: map;

auto hexstr = "16D81B16E091F31BEF";

ubyte[] bytes = (hexstr.length % 2 ? "0" ~ hexstr : hexstr)
                .chunks(2)
                .map!(twoDigits => twoDigits.parse!ubyte(16))
                .array();
```

Comment: Edited slightly to handle non multiple-of-2 length strings